# CQ - how to know an Osgi Config factory PID in advance

Tags: osgi, aem, sling

Adobe's docs say:

> When making a Factory Configuration append -<identifier> to the name.
>
> As in: org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config-<identifier>
>
> Where  is replaced by free text that you (must) enter to identify the instance (you cannot omit this information); for example:
>
> org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config-MINE

This implies the "free text" is an identifier, not just a name. I was hoping it would be the service PID.

I'm setting up an instance of the JDBC Connections Pool. I've got an xml config file in my /jcr_root/apps/<my-app>/config directory named "com.day.commons.datasource.jdbcpool.JdbcPoolService-mypid.xml". Installing the package containing xml file creates the expected, correctly-named sling:OsgiConfig node. This, in turn, does create a configured instance of the service, but the PID is com.day.commons.datasource.jdbcpool.JdbcPoolService.<random-guid>.

Is there some way to know what the PID will be in advance so that it can be referenced?

Comment: No. It's a random UUID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to know this id in advance. I aleady asked on the OSGi dev list if this can be enhanced. It would be nice to identify factory configs in a human readable way. Unfortunately the response was that it is not necessary or similar. Maybe if some more people ask for it :-)

Comment: I guess I don't need it because I can filter the services using a wildcard in place of the UUID, and any other service property. For JdbcPoolService, I can use `(&(service.pid=com.day.commons.datasource.jdbcpool.JdbcPoolService*)(datasource.name=whatever))`